# How can I get visual inheritance working at high dpi values?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, highdpi, visual-inheritance

I have the following example form `TForm1` with two buttons (`BitBtn`):

[image: base form]

Additionally I have a second form `TForm2` which is derived from the first form.
The second button is moved to the left and another button is added:

[image: derived form]

At runtime (Windows 7), the second form looks like this:

[image: standard font size]

If I change font scaling to 125%, my form looks like this:

[image: increased font size]

Somehow, the new button has the wrong position and the wrong size.
*What can I do about this?*

I used the following `.dfm` files (shortened):

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object BitBtn1: TBitBtn
    Left = 8
    Top = 8
    Width = 105
    Height = 105
    Caption = 'BitBtn1'
  end
  object BitBtn2: TBitBtn
    Left = 359
    Top = 8
    Width = 105
    Height = 105
    Caption = 'BitBtn2'
  end
end

inherited Form2: TForm2
  Caption = 'Form2'
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  inherited BitBtn2: TBitBtn
    Left = 191
    Top = 7
    ExplicitLeft = 191
    ExplicitTop = 7
  end
  object BitBtn3: TBitBtn
    Left = 359
    Top = 8
    Width = 105
    Height = 104
    Caption = 'BitBtn3'
  end
end
```

Class files are left unchanged as the designer generates them. They contain no relevant code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a possible solution myself: one has to overwrite `ReadState` with
the following code:

```
procedure TForm2.ReadState(Reader: TReader);
begin
  IntPtr(FReserved) := 0;
  inherited;
end;
```

This looks strange. How does it work?

I looked at the `VCL` source code and found
that scaling after form loading is done in `TForm.ReadState(...)`.  Apparrently, a protected
field `FReserved` of `TControl` is used to store the currently applied `DPI` value:

- at first, all components of my base class `dfm` are read
- then they are scaled and positioned correctly
- and the currently applied `DPI` value is stored in `FReserved`
- afterwards `ReadState` is called again, for the `dfm` file of the derived class
- but because of the value in `FReserved`, scaling is not applied to components of the derived form

So, one idea would be to reset the cached `DPI` value before reading the components. It scales the components of `Form1` twice, but this doesn't hurt as the original sizes and positions are remembered as base value for scaling and the result is exactly the same.

Comment: You should report this to Embarcadero so they can fix it.

Comment: I would have reported it, but as it turns out [it is is already reported](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-12971). One of the more annoying consequences of requiring a login for the quality portal is that search engines can not index the content. Even though, I found the issue with my first search query, so the internal search engine is working properly.

Comment: Additionally, this seems to be fixed with `Delphi 10.1 Berlin`.